# Accessing vector values from a class_Type name not allowed error

Tags: c++, vector, typename

I store unsigned values in a vector and I need to use these values in another class. I get errors when trying to return vector values in a function and I don't know what I'm doing wrong! here is part of my code:

```
class Rider
{
  friend istream &operator>>(istream &in, Rider &rhs);

public:
  Rider(const string &name = ""): m_name(name){}

  const string &name() const {return m_name;}
  const string &team() const {return m_team;}
  const string &country() const {return m_country;}
  //const unsigned &numOfSatges() const {return m_tv;}

  typedef vector<unsigned> TimeVector;
  const vector<unsigned> & get() const{return TimeVector;) //Error: Type Name is not allowed!

private:

  string m_name;
  string m_team;
  string m_country;

  //unsigned m_numOfStages;

  TimeVector m_tv;

};
```

Here is where I'm trying to access the unsigned values stored in the vector:

```
class Match_Stage : public unary_function<const Rider&, bool>
{
public:
  Match_Stage(const unsigned stage) : m_stage(stage){}
  bool operator()( const Rider &rider) const
  {
    return rider.TimeVector == m_stage; //Error: Type Name is not allowed!
  }

private:
   unsigned m_stage;
};
```

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1):

`TimeVector` is a typename. You are using it as if it was a variable. It is like saying

```
int == 42;
```

You need a variable:

```
int i = 3;
i == 42;
```

What you probably wanted was to return an instance of `TimeVector` in your class:

```
typedef vector<unsigned> TimeVector;
const vector<unsigned> & get() const{return m_tv;)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding that fast. when I tried your solution, i got the error: expected and expression. Any idea what I'm missing? thanks

Comment: @samy you are most likely doing something else wrong. But I see you already have a `TimeVector` data member, so maybe you just want to use that one.